# How to know if a number is in the x interval of a group

Tags: algorithm, logic, intervals

I have a problem with the logic of an algorithm I need.

I have a group of "y" amount of elements and I need to divide it into the amount of elements in other group of size "x" and then find out if the "a" element of the second group is in the "a" group of the first one.

For example if I have this 2 groups

A = {1,2,3,4}

B = {1,2,3,...,100}

100/4 is 25 so the function should be true if A=1 and B=[1,25) or A=2 and B=[25,50) and so on

How can I make the algorithm to make this with variable group sizes?
I'm working on java but just the logic is enough

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do the two groups always contain the numbers from 1 to x (or from 1 to y)?                   
Which output do you expect if `y mod x != 0`?

Comment: Yes, x and y are always starting from 1.

If y is not divisible by x it would be just fine to round the number to the closest integer and leave the numbers that are left over in any of the groups.

For example if y is 110 and x is 4 it would be fine to make groups 1-24 25-49 50-74 75-110 or 1-34 35-59 50-84 85-110 or 1-27 28- 56 57-83 84-110 or any other combination it's not an exact thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `y` is divisible by `x` the solution is simple:
`x/y` will be seen as the `length` of the intervals that we should consider. If we assume that `x=4` and `y=100` there will be four intervals of `length == 25`: [1, 25], [26, 50], [51, 75], [76, 100] (note that these intervals are closed, in opposition to your question, since if they were open the last element wouldn't have been included).
So the inputs of the algorithm will be `a` (which represents the a-th interval) and `b` (a number between 1 and `y`). If `b` is in the a-th interval, then the output is `true`.
`b` is in the a-th interval iff `b > length * (a-1)` and `b <= length * a`.

The following code implements a function `f` which works even if `y % x != 0`: in this case, the last interval will include more elements (the number of these additional elements is the reminder `y%x`).

```java
public static boolean f(int a, int b, int x, int y) {
    int length = y / x;

    int reminder = y % x;
    if (a != x) {
        reminder = 0;
    }

    return b > length * (a - 1) && b <= length * a + reminder;
}
```

You can add additional controls to the function.